# Data for average monthly high/low by zipcode

Tags: data, weather

I am looking for data that will provide average monthly temperatures by zip codes in the US. I require only a year or two worth of historical data, as I am only looking for general trends.

[Wunderground](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/planner) used to provide summaries like this through their API, but they no longer provide free api keys.

Other APIs provide historical data per day, which I can aggregate for monthly averages. However, this would quickly hit the API limits. Please let me know if there is a data dump, or API I could hit that may have this information.

Answer (score 1):

The [PRISM Climate Group](http://prism.oregonstate.edu/) hosts a number of weather-related data that you could spatially join to zipcode data.